# display icon dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox when i enter and finish typing next text box appears dynamically
Eg:textbox1 textbox2 some text here
When i keep my cursor on some text here,i need to display icon after i remove my cursor from some text here that icon should not display.

How do i do it? know that this is possible in jquery but i am new to jquery
can any one help me?

Comment: Do you want the icon to appear when you hover over the text field? Or after you hover out?

Comment: @Ibrahim AshShohail: when i hoever on some text here,i need icon to display and when i remove my cursor form some text here icon should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your "some text here" in an element like a span or div or whatever.
2. use jQuery to select that particular element and attach hover behaviour to it.
3. in the hover handler, toggle visibility of your icon.

The jQuery hover documentation should get you almost there.  Look at the example.  It's adding a dynamic span element, but it can be replaced w/ image quite easily...

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Is this crt $("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span><img src="ddd" /></span>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);
ul lifsf/li /ul

Answer (score 0):

This should be better just incase you had another span after the icon.

```
$("li").hover(
  function () { $(this).append($("<img id="text-icon" src="icon.png" />")); },
  function () { $(this).find("#text-icon").remove(); }
);
```

Or you could have the img tag in your current markup, and use jQuery to show and hide it:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () { $(this).find("#text-icon").show(); },
  function () { $(this).find("#text-icon").hide(); }
);
```

or use CSS and the :hover selector to change the "display" status.

```
#text-icon { display: none; }
span:hover #text-icon { display: inline-block; }
```